# Memory leak when I replace a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I have just started to use LeakCanary and when I replace a Fragment, every time leaks increase. This is the LeakCanary report:

```
android.widget.LinearLayout instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.home.app1.PostFragment received Fragment#onDestroyView() callback 
     (references to its views should be cleared to prevent leaks))
```

This is my Fragment Replace code:

```
public void change(Fragment fragment) {

    ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

            .replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment, "fragment")
            .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

So I research on SO and some people say views must be clenead in `onDestroyView`. Then I tried this in `onDestroyView`: `fragmentView=null;` but nothing was changed. Also tried this:

```
if (view.getParent() != null) {
        ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
    }
```

But again nothing was changed. So I tried to make all views null like below:

```
   @Override
   public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    backButton=null;
    swipeLayout=null;
    imageView=null; ...etc.
   }
```

Eventually leaking warnings on LeakCanary disappeared. But I think this is not a solution and does not make sense because there may be many views. So what's the solution to avoid this leaks? Thanks.

Comment: Add your leak trace please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I tried to make all views null like below
>
> Eventually leaking warnings on LeakCanary disappeared.

You've found the solution - you were holding onto `View` references (your `backButton`, `swipeLayout`, `imageView`, etc.) after they were removed and supposed to be destroyed (`onDestroyView`). Since holding a reference to them prevents them from being garbage collected, that's a memory leak.

> But I think this is not a solution and does not make sense because there may be
>   many views. So what's the solution to avoid this leaks?

If you're storing `View`s in member variables manually, that's the best solution.  You could use `findViewById` to find it every time, but I wouldn't recommend it because you'll incur a performance penalty from repeatedly traversing the View hierarchy.

You can avoid both of those problems by using the [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) feature of the Android development tooling.  With that, you'll just have one Binding object to get rid of.

You could also use [Butter Knife](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61743869/memory-leak-when-replace-a-fragment) to manage your View variables for you - see the `unbinder.unbind();` pattern mentioned on that page.

Comment: I understand your suggest. But there are a lot of code and I have no much time for project. So I can't replace all `findViewById` methods for now. So in this situation should I continue to use first solution(null out) ?

Comment: That's probably the least work to do if your time is limited, I think, yes.

Comment: I don't think it really matters.  I usually do it after for consistency with the other lifecycle callbacks.